# Generating all possible "stupid" passwords constructed by 5 elements in Java

Tags: java

I've got to write a Java code with inputs **n** and **l** that prints all possible "stupid" passwords, constructed of the five elements:

1. an integer from **1** to **n**;
2. an integer from **1** to **n**;
3. a letter from the first **l** letters of the alphabet;
4. a letter from the first **l** letters of the alphabet;
5. an integer from **1** to **n**, which is **larger** than the first two;

So far my code is the following:

```
import java.util.*;

public class passwords {   
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n, l;
        int n1, n2, n3;
        n = scan.nextInt();
        l = scan.nextInt();
        scan.close();

        Random rnd = new Random();
        String alphabet = "abcdefghjklmnopqrstvuwxyz";

        for(n1 = 1; n1 < n; n1++){
            for(n2 = 1; n2 < n; n2++){
                for(n3 = 2; n3 <= n; n3++){
                    for(int m = l; m < alphabet.length(); m++){
                        char nc = (char) (rnd.nextInt(l) + 'a');
                        char nc1 = (char) (rnd.nextInt(l) + 'a');  

                        System.out.println(n1 + "" + n2 + "" + nc + "" + nc1 + "" + n3);
                    } 
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It seems to kind of work but there are either missing or repeated combinations among the printed ones.

Comment: for repetions why not add them to a list or something which you could check against instead, print that then at the end

Comment: Your algorithm is wrong. Why do you use a random function while you have to output ALL password ?

Comment: @Aman whaaaaat?

Comment: @luk2302 loop under loop under loop is definitely a bad practice, and i have gone through it.. when akamai was crashing because of the super nested loop

Comment: By element, you mean character ? Because the first two are the same.

Comment: @Aman you are mixing up two completely different things. Yes, nested loops can be considered bad practice. **No**, nested loops will not crash the server - bugs and exceptions "crash servers", they might be more likely when having a lot of nested loops. But in this situation I might say the nested loops are okay since they are straight forward and nothing complex is happening inside them.

Comment: @OP: You already state *"It seems to kind of work but there are either missing or repeated combinations among the printed ones"* - please give the sample input you are testing with, the output you currently receive and the *expected* output.

Comment: @Aman Given the algorithm, nested loops are perfectly fine and entirely *not* bad practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are actually pretty close. A few points have already been pointed out in the comments:

- do not use Random
- use two loops for the letters
- constrain `n3` on `Math.max` of the first two numbers

That will result in:

```
for (n1 = 1; n1 < n; n1++) {
    for (n2 = 1; n2 < n; n2++) {
        int max = Math.max(n1, n2) + 1;
        for (n3 = max; n3 <= n; n3++) {
            for (char c1 = 0; c1 < l; c1++) {
                char nc1 = (char)(c1 + 'a');
                for (char c2 = 0; c2 < l; c2++) {
                    char nc2 = (char)(c2 + 'a');

                    System.out.println("" + n1 + n2 + nc1 + nc2 + n3);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that you *might* need to change the edge constraints of the `for` loops, I am not sure about them.

For the inputs `2,3` this results in

> 11aa2
>   11ab2
>   11ac2
>   11ba2
>   11bb2
>   11bc2
>   11ca2
>   11cb2
>   11cc2

---

[@Andreas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5221149/andreas) correctly noted that you can simplify the `char` loops in the following way (dropping `c1` and `c2` completely):

```
for (char nc1 = 'a'; nc1 < 'a' + l; nc1++)
    for (char nc2 = 'a'; nc2 < 'a' + l; nc2++)
        System.out.println("" + n1 + n2 + nc1 + nc2 + n3);
    }
}
```

Comment: `n3` should start at `max + 1`. The print statement can be simplified to `System.out.println("" + n1 + n2 + nc1 + nc2 + n3);`, since the left-associative nature ensures that all `+` operators are string concatenations.

Comment: Also, why not just loop `for (char nc1 = 'a'; nc1 < 'a' + l; nc1++)`

Answer (score 0):

You have some very odd segments in your algorithm.

1. Why are you Randomly generating the chars, but generating every possible number - You will need a loop for the characters, not randomly generated. Random generation does not ensure that you will output every character in a given range if you generate on a fixed interval.
2. You need to make sure the second input constraint is smaller than the alphabet - This is implemented by having the condition on the character for loops as the Minimum between the input l and the size of the alphabet.
3. You don't ensure the third integer is greater than the previous two - This can be implemented by starting the third loop from the Maximum of the previous two.

The resolved code is as follows:

```
        for(n1 = 1; n1 <= n; n1++) {
            for(n2 = 1; n2 <= n; n2++) {
                for(n3 = Math.max(n1, n2) + 1; n3 <= n; n3++) {
                    for(char c1 = 'a'; c1 < Math.min(l, alphabet.length()) + 'a'; c1++) {
                        for (char c2 = 'a'; c2 < Math.min(l, alphabet.length()) + 'a'; c2++) {
                            String out = String.format("%s%s%s%s%s", n1, n2, c1, c2, n3);
                            System.out.println(out);
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }
```